# Check case-sensitivity from Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, filesystems, case-sensitive

ALL,

Is there a way to check if I have a case sensitive file system from Cocoa? Or I will have to execute [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71357/how-to-check-if-my-hd-is-case-sensitive-or-not) (`diskutil info /`)and grep it appropriately?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [`NSURL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl?language=objc)'s method `getResourceValue:forKey:error:` or `resourceValuesForKeys:error:` and the [`NSURLResourceKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlresourcekey?language=objc) keys `NSURLVolumeSupportsCasePreservedNamesKey` and `NSURLVolumeSupportsCaseSensitiveNamesKey`.

Comment: so I can do something like `int id; [NSURL getResourceValue: id forKey: NSURLVolumeSupportsCaseSensitiveNamesKey error: nil]; if( id == YES ) print "Sensitive";`? Am I right? And the method is static, so I don't need to instantiate `NSURL` object?

Comment: It is an instance method, the URL is needed to identify which volume is being queried. If you are only interested in the boot volume you can use a URL for the root (the path `@"/"`). Your example call isn't quite right, the result is an *object* and returned via the first argument which must be the address of a variable. For these two resource keys the returned value is an `NSNumber` object, you can use the `boolValue` method to obtain the actual `BOOL` value to test. Try writing some code and if you get stuck ask a new question showing your code and explaining your problem. HTH

Comment: I finally tried to write some code but got a compiler error. As suggested I will open another thread. Thx.

Comment: question created here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57531800/compilation-fails-calling-cocoa-function-from-c. Could you take a look, if you can?